# Calculating power in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Using python 2.7.3 and pandas 0.10.1, I am getting a deprecation warning when I try to use the ** operation to calculate power (mathematical, not thermodynamic).  In the documentation, it covers the use of add, sub, mul, and div for Series and DataFrame arithmetic operations.  However, I cannot find anything covering ** for these, as in 3 ** 2 = 9.  What can I do besides use ** and hope for the best?

Comment: Can you add the warning you are getting?

Comment: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3578
    FutureWarning)
FutureWarning: TimeSeries broadcasting along DataFrame index by default is deprecated. Please use DataFrame.<op> to explicitly broadcast arithmetic operations along the index

Comment: I would have expected something like answer = foo.pow(bar) in line with the other operations.  (And thanks for helping me.)

Comment: Did that not work?  It looks like the DataFrame should have a pow method.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\b29.py", line 434, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\b29.py", line 193, in main
    sys_rets, sys_nav, ret, mkt_wts, scenario, win, exponent)
  File "C:\Python27\b29tools.py", line 417, in applytoplevelkickout
    factor = 1.0 - arg.pow(exponent) # invalid
AttributeError: 'TimeSeries' object has no attribute 'pow'

Comment: Apologies - edited my previous comment to provide the correct error message.  There is no pow method yet, I think.

Comment: Right, a Series object doesn't have the pow method but a DataFrame does.  Is exponent a dataframe?  Or are you doing a DataFrame exponentiation elsewhere?  Exponentiation between a series and a scalar should not be deprecated.

Comment: I suspect you have multiple exponentiations in your code and the one you are working on is not the one giving you the deprecation warning.

Answer (score 6):

To calculate exponentiation between a time series and a data frame one should do:

```
dataFrame.pow(timeSeries, axis=0)
```

To calculate exponentiation between a series and a scalar one can still do:

```
timeSeries ** exponent
```

Comment: OK, thanks.  I'll do some more digging on my end, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Just to complete things here, my error was in using the method incorrectly.  Thanks to Pace for helping.