# Looping through dataframe and creating a function for optimization

Tags: function, optimization, pandas

I have written a small code in python and it works fine.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize



"""define power and coefficients"""

power = 0.6
coefficient = 5.6

"""define objective function"""

def func(x,sign=1.0):
    return sign*sum(coefficient*(x[0:]**power))

""" define constraints"""

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[1] - 2 * x[1] + 2},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -x[2] - 2 * x[1] + 6},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -x[0] + 2 * x[1] + 2})

""" define bounds"""

bnds = ((0.7, 1.3), (0.7, 1.3), (0.7,1.3))

"""initial values of the variables"""

x0 = np.array([1.1, 3.9,5.6])

"""run the optimization  algorithm"""

res = minimize(func, x0, method='SLSQP',bounds = bnds,constraints=cons,
           options={'disp': True})

"""print the results"""

print(res.x)
```

---

This code contains an objective function

```
def func(x,sign=1.0):
    return sign*sum(coefficient*(x[0:]**power))
```

and the initial values as

```
x0 = np.array([1.1, 3.9,5.6])
```

But it is all hard coded . I want to form them on run time.

i.e. I have an csv file, I will read that into a dataframe Structure of CSV file is

```
DV_Name Investment
DV1     1.2
DV2     1.2
DV3     1.3
DV4     1.2
DV5     1.2
DV6     4.5
DV7     1.2
DV8     2.7
DV9     1.2
DV10    1.2
```

I used the `pd.DataFrame.from_csv`.

What do I have to do to have my objective function in the form `coeff*(DV1 ^ power + DV2^power + DV3^power ......DV10^power)` And my initial value array x0 as values of investment i.e. investment(0), investment(1)....and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can raise a column of your `DataFrame` using [`pow(exponent)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pow.html) like so:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3,4], 'bar':[5,6,7,8]})
>>> df['foo'].pow(2) # raise all elements of the column 'foo' to the power 2
0     1
1     4
2     9
3    16
Name: foo, dtype: int64
```

Or you can just do `df['bar'] ** 2` as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16084253/2071807)

You can then sum the elements of one column using [`sum()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) like this:

```
>>> df['foo'].pow(2).sum()
30
```

That should be enough to get you started!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work it out:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default')
```

"""Read the input file into the dataframe"""

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('C:\Users\prashant.mudgal\Downloads\Test.csv')
```

"""subset of DV"""

```
dv= df['DV']
```

"""Objective fucntion """
"""Power additive function"""
"""sign = 1.0 has been added for maximization"""
""" corresponding matrices for the coefficient, power are use"""

```
def func(dv,sign=1.0) :
return sign*(sum(df['Coefficient'].values[0:]*dv[0:]**df['Power'].values[0:]))
```

""" define bounds"""

```
bnds = ((0.7, 1.3),(0.7, 1.3),(0.7,1.3),(0.7,1.3),(0.7,1.3),(0.7,1.3),(0.7,1.3),    (0.7,1.3),(0.7,1.3))
```

"""bnds = ((df['LB'].values,df['UB'].values))"""

""" define constraints"""

```
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  dv[1] - 2 * dv[1] + 2},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -dv[2] - 2 * dv[1] + 6},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -dv[0] + 2 * dv[1] + 2})
```

"""run optimization using sum of least squares method"""
"""s.values is the initial estimated values which are given by the investment column in the csv file"""

```
res = minimize(func, df['Inv'].values,args=(-1.0,),method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds,
           options={'disp': True})
```

"""Print the results"""

```
print (res)
```

But I have a new problem the bounds that I have created , they are hard coded and I don't want that. I want them to be read from a dataframe or a file 
My file has 2 columns

```
upperbound  Lowerbound
1.3               0.7
1.3               0.7
1.3               0.7.........
```

now I want to form my bounds after reading some dataframe something like

```
bnds = ((df['Upperbound'],df['lowerbound']))
```

so there will be as many pairs as specified in the file.